# Calculation on a list of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of matrix, e.g. `list(M1,M2,M3,M4)`

I would like to get a matrix that add all the matrix `M1+M2+M3+M4` and divide each row by `rowSums(M1)+rowSums(M2)+rowSums(M3)+rowSums(M4)`.

Here an example list,

```
lst <- list(M1 = matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2, 2), M2 = matrix(c(2,6,3,7), 2, 2))
lst
#> $M1
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]    4    5
#> 
#> $M2
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    3
#> [2,]    6    7
```

where my desired outcome would be,

```
(1+2)/((2+1)+(2+3)) = 0.375      (2+3)/((2+1)+(2+3)) = 0.625
(4+6)/((6+7)+(4+5)) = 0.4545455  (5+7)/((6+7)+(4+5)) = 0.5454545
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try

```
Reduce(`+`, lst)/ sum(sapply(lst, rowSums))
```

Or

```
Reduce(`+`, lst)/ sum(unlist(lst))
```

#### Update

Based on the update by the OP (using the OP's dataset)

```
Reduce(`+`, lst)/rowSums(sapply(lst, rowSums))
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.3750000 0.6250000
#[2,] 0.4545455 0.5454545
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(matrix(1:16, 4, 4), matrix(1:16, 4, 4))
```

Comment: it's been a time that i've asked this question but i have one more question as: what if I want to take each 3 matrix of the list and do the same operation, let's say i have lisft=(M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9)  so i want to do the same calculation for (M1,M2,M3) ,then (M4,M5,M6),then (M7,M8,M9).thank you

Comment: @Maha Please post as a new question

Answer (score 3):

You can use a 3-dimensional array and `apply()`

```
M1 <- matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2)
M2 <- matrix(c(2,6,3,7), 2)
L <- list(M1, M2)
M <- array(unlist(L), dim=c(2,2,2)) # or: M <- array(c(M1, M2), dim=c(2,2,2))

apply(M, 1:2, sum) / apply(M, 1, sum)
# > apply(M, 1:2, sum) / apply(M, 1, sum)
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.3750000 0.6250000
# [2,] 0.4545455 0.5454545
```

and in rowSums notation (thx to user20650):

```
rowSums(M, dims=2) / rowSums(M)
```

Comment: it's been a time that i've asked this question but i have one more question as: what if I want to take each 3 matrix of the list and do the same operation, let's say i have lisft=(M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9) so i want to do the same calculation for (M1,M2,M3) ,then (M4,M5,M6),then (M7,M8,M9).thank you